# Select dynamic html id in selenium web driver

Tags: selenium, xpath

In project we are using auto suggestion textbox in asp.net as and when I enter 'Wo' 10 names are display which are starting with 'Wo'

Now, I want to write script in Selenium web driver and get any one id from auto suggestion textbox

Its id change every time, so, How can i capture that id?

I try using dynamic xpath, but still not get

the code is:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='vendorName']")).sendKeys("W0");


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[starts-with(@id,'ud-id-')]")).click();
```

please help

Comment: Please, add html code.

Comment: Did you try the documentation? http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/appendix_locating_techniques.jsp

Comment: yes, I read it but i didn't get the solution. My html code is :